# Get first word of all strings in lists

Tags: python, string, list, split, strip

I have a CSV file which I'm reading in like below. I need to get the first word of all the strings. I know how to get first letter but I'm not sure how I can get words.

```
['diffuse systemic sclerosis', 'back', 'public on july 15 2008']
['diffuse systemic sclerosis', 'forearm', 'public on may 9 2014']
```

I want my output to be

```
diffuse
back
public
forearm
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension , and [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function  :

```
>>> l=['diffuse systemic sclerosis', 'back', 'public on july 15 2008']
>>> [i.split()[0] for i in l]
['diffuse', 'back', 'public']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use comprehension

```
>>> l = [['diffuse systemic sclerosis', 'back', 'public on july 15 2008']
,['diffuse systemic sclerosis', 'forearm', 'public on may 9 2014']]

>>> list({i.split()[0] for j in l for i in j})
['back', 'diffuse', 'forearm', 'public']
```

Comment: @BhargavRato, No idea, your solution seems to answer the question better than the accepted one.

Comment: how do I extract the first comma separated element from each row from a list of list as shown in your example above? From your example I would want to extract diffuse systemic sclerosis and diffuse systemic sclerosis and make a new list with these first workds

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [
    ['diffuse systemic sclerosis', 'back', 'public on july 15 2008'],
    ['diffuse systemic sclerosis', 'forearm', 'public on may 9 2014']
    ]
d = lambda o: [a.split().pop(0) for a in o]
r = lambda a,b: d(a) + d(b)
print "\n".join(set(reduce(r, l)))
>>> 
public
forearm
diffuse
back
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) in a list comprehension, noting that you can specify `maxsplit` to reduce the number of operations:

```
L = ['diffuse systemic sclerosis', 'back', 'public on july 15 2008']

res = [i.split(maxsplit=1)[0] for i in L]
# ['diffuse', 'back', 'public']
```

You can also perform the same operations functionally:

```
from operator import itemgetter, methodcaller

splitter = methodcaller('split', maxsplit=1)
res = list(map(itemgetter(0), map(splitter, L)))
```

Across multiple lists, if you wish to maintain the order with which you observe unique first words, you can use the [`itertool` `unique_everseen` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes), also found in the [`more_itertools`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.unique_everseen) library:

```
from itertools import chain
from more_itertool import unique_everseen

L1 = ['diffuse systemic sclerosis', 'back', 'public on july 15 2008']
L2 = ['diffuse systemic sclerosis', 'forearm', 'public on may 9 2014']

res = list(unique_everseen(i.split(maxsplit=1)[0] for i in chain(L1, L2)))

# ['diffuse', 'back', 'public', 'forearm']
```